# creating a menu-oriented with different levels in Joomla

Tags: joomla, menu, module

I'm trying to create a menu-oriented module with the following menu :

Menu Shops :

- Shops (category blog)
- - shop 1 (article)
- - shop 2 (article)
- - shop 3 (article)
- - shop 4 (article)
- - shop 5 (article)

I'd like to only show the 5 sub-menus shop 1 -> shop 5 in my module. When I create the module (Module Manager/Module Menu), I choose 'shops' as base item and '2' as start level. Unfortunately, it doesn't show anything. 
But when I choose '1' as start level and '2' as end level, it only shows Shops.
I'm using joomla 3

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla menu modules cache is not working properly in these situations, just disable the cache of the module.